# MongoDB not connecting to the server

Tags: mongodb, flask

Every time I try to connect to my mongodb atlas via my app, I keep getting this error.

ERROR 'f len([h for h in host if "/" in h]) > 1: TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable'

```
from turtle import turtlesize
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from pymongo import MongoClient


app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config['SECRET KEY'] = ''
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv:// admin:admin@sunbeam.cb2bg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongodb_client = MongoClient(app)
db = mongodb_client.db
cluster = db['Studentsdb']
collection = cluster['students']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('student_forms'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
    

@app.route("/")
def products():
    #return "<p>This is a proejcts page</p>"
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/student_forms", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def student_forms():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        gender = request.form['gender']
        class_admit = request.form['class']
        dob = request.form['birthdate']
        collection.insert_one({'name':name, 'gender':gender, 'class': class_admit, 'dob': dob})
        return redirect(url_for('student_forms'))
    return render_template('studentform.html', form=student_forms)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: if len([h for h in host if "/" in h]) > 1:
TypeError: 'Flask' object is not iterable

Comment: There's no stack trace with line numbers, etc.?

Comment: What happens with `mongodb_client = MongoClient(app.config['MONGO_URI'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a number of issues but the first is your connection string should not have a space:

```
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv:// admin:admin@sunbeam.cb2bg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
->
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://admin:admin@sunbeam.cb2bg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Comment: still getting the error after the correction